# How To Get The Unique Names For All Actions In A CRM Org?

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

This is how I'm currently apply to return all Actions in an Org:

```cs
var qe = new QueryExpression("workflow");
qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
qe.Criteria.AddCondition("category", ConditionOperator.Equal, 3); // Action
qe.Criteria.AddCondition("parentworkflowid", ConditionOperator.Null);
```

The only problem is when I look at the Unique Name returned, it is returning the Process Name i.e. `My Custom Action` not the actual Unique Name i.e. `new_MyCustomAction`.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Proposition:

Use this fetchxml to retrieve the activated actions Name + full unique name with the prefix.

```html
<fetch>
<entity name="workflow" >
    <attribute name="name" />
    <filter type="and" >
     <condition attribute="category" operator="eq" value="3" />
     <condition attribute="statuscode" operator="eq" value="2" />
     <condition attribute="type" operator="eq" value="2" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="sdkmessage" from="sdkmessageid" to="sdkmessageid" link-type="inner" alias="sdkMsg" >
     <attribute name="name" />
    </link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Processes are not tied to a publisher, so they don't have a unique name with a prefix like a field.

However Actions display a prefix and CRM internally stores it somewhere, the proof is that the prefix is different if the action is created outside a solution or inside.

But when you get the `uniquename` attribute of an action (standard workflows don't contain this attribute, they only contain `name`) it doesn't have the prefix, and CRM uses it (stripped down) in combination with the ID to make it unique inside solutions:

```xml
        <Workflows>
            <Workflow WorkflowId="{ed949164-510c-409a-8b85-8a6917fd57d6}" Name="Update Name">
            <XamlFileName>/Workflows/UpdateName-ED949164-510C-409A-8B85-8A6917FD57D6.xaml</XamlFileName>
            <Category>3</Category>
            <UniqueName>UpdateName</UniqueName>
```

It's a bug? It's a feature? It's both? *Ai posteri l'ardua sentenza*

Comment: For the first time in our SO relationship, I'm not sure I entirely agree with you Guido.  When [creating a new action](http://www.powerobjects.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/112113_1744_ActionsinDy2.png), there is a prefix with the unique name.  When you [generate them](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B0By9PBv_3cDU215bzZkSnBVUVk&export=download), the prefix is included.  And when you [call them late bound] (https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2013/09/27/introduction-to-actions-in-crm-2013.aspx) the prefix is required.

Comment: Sorry, I did my test with a workflow assuming that will be valid also for actions, I will do a couple of tests right now

Comment: Any suggestions on a good channel to go through to get a more definitive answer from Microsoft?

Comment: try to open a suggestion on connect site. An alternative is dynamics crm facebook group, there are some microsoft employees that work on dynamics crm that check it.

Comment: Didn't know about the crm facebook group!  I'll put something out on the connect site.

Comment: I've added a request, feel free to upvote it. https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedbackdetail/view/946885

Comment: Anyone know how one can create a action/workflow with solution prefix from SDK/Code. When i try its already created with new_ prefix

Answer (score 0):

the information about the prefixed custom action unique name is in the sdkmessagerequest entity, which could be linked to sdkmessage entity and the workflow entity has an sdkmessageid.
the unique name for Custom Actions comes from the fact that they are considered as custom sdk messages.
hope this helps!